# When the function is neither concave nor convex?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If I remember correctly multivariate function is convex when

$f''_{11}(x,y) \leq 0, f''_{22}(x,y) \leq 0$ and $f''_{11}(x,y)f''_{22}(x,y) - (f''_{12}(x,y))^2 \geq 0$

and concave when

$f''_{11}(x,y) \geq 0, f''_{22}(x,y) \geq 0$ and $f''_{11}(x,y)f''_{22}(x,y) - (f''_{12}(x,y))^2 \geq 0$

could anyone explain me what are the conditions for a multivariate function to be neither convex, nor concave?

Also can you show me the conditions on example $x^ay^{1-a}$ where $a \leq 1$.

Does it have to do something with the fact that for the above function this holds?

$f''_{11}(x,y) > 0, f''_{22}(x,y) > 0$ and $f''_{11}(x,y)f''_{22}(x,y) - (f''_{12}(x,y))^2 = 0$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is the other way. $f$ (twice continuously differentiable) is convex if and only if the hessian $f''$ is positive semidefinite. Over $\mathbb R^2$ it is exactly the case if $f''_{1,1}, f''_{2,2} \ge 0$ and $ \det f'' \ge 0$.

Comment: The conditions for $f$ not to be convex or concave is that it is neither convex, so the first condition is false, nor concave, so the second condition is also false (with the appropriate corrections to the conditions). Also, I get $f''_{11}(x,y) < 0, f''_{22}(x,y) < 0$ where they are defined.